# Is there a generic SNMP OID to get CPU fan speed on a Linux system?

Tags: linux, snmp, qnap, oid

I am trying to get the CPU fan speed of a QNAP NAS through SNMP. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a QNAP-specific OID for this, based on the QNAP MIB.
Is anyone aware of a generic OID for this in Linux perhaps that I could try?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's such a thing like a CPU fan in your specific model ? I had a QNAP TS-453A until a couple of months ago and I remember there being only a System Fan (which is, the big fan on the back of the case, which exhausted heat for the whole system, disks included).
Since I can't download the whole MIB now (QNAP makes it available for download directly from within the NAS GUI, which I don't have anymore) I've looked around. It seems the OID and name to get the System Fan speed changed recently ([QTS 4.5.1 changes SNMP MIB #6](https://github.com/zottelbeyer/QNAP-collectdinfluxdbgrafana/issues/6)) but you might be able to find it with the following name: "NAS-MIB::sysFanSpeedEX".

Comment: My model has three fans that have sensors: two system fans and a CPU fan. The speeds of these three can be seen in the web-ui System Status app.
I'm already pulling the system fan speeds through snmp, but for some reason the QNAP MIB doesn't have a CPU fan speed entry.
I was hoping there may be a generic/standard way, as I'm using such a way for pulling more detailed network stats as well, which are also not available through the QNAP MIB.
Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: I understand your point. Once upon a time, in standard linux distros, there were lm_sensors and net-snmp that could be combined together to access system sensors via SNMP (and system sensors might include a CPU fan in some instances), but QNAP is a linux-based machine, not a full debian or the like. Don't know if there's a way to install them over there and have them working.

Comment: Good point. I don't think I'm not going to go down the path of installing additional packages just for this. QNAP did update SNMP in a supposedly significant way in 4.5.2, so I'm trying to get someone who has already updated to that version to share the mib. Who knows, maybe they've added some new metrics, including this. :)